# onclick does not fire in a link that is created by clicking another link

Tags: javascript, onclick

Javascript function writelink creates a link that fires function hiya.  It works when I define and invoke writelink inside script.  But, I want the body to contain another link that calls writelink to create a link.  This final link fails to fire (but works if I replace hiya with alert).  I am a total novice, so I hope it is something obvious.  The main idea is that I have to create some links from code, and these have to fire to execute some more code.  (If you want me to do this a totally different way, please try to give me a complete example.)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
function hiya (num){
  alert("hiya " + num);
}
function writelink (num){
  var htmlstr = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"hiya(" + num + ");return false;\">link" + num + "</a>";
  document.write(htmlstr);
}
writelink(1);
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <br>
 <a href="#" onclick="writelink(3);return false;">link2</a>;
 <br>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.write(htmlstr)` replaces the entire DOM with the link / `htmlstr` you are about to insert. Use pure javascript to create the link(s) instead :

```
function writelink(num){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.innerHTML='link '+num;
  link.href='#';
  link.onclick=hiya(num);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

Just replace `writelink()` with the code above.

You would typically want to add the link to a certain element instead of just `<body>`, lets say a `<div>` with the id `menu` :

```
var cnt = document.getElementById('menu');
cnt.appendChild(link);
```

---

### update

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="writelink(2);">link2</a>
<script>
function hiya(num) {
  alert("hiya " + num);
}
function writelink(num){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.innerHTML='link '+num;
  link.href='#';
  link.onclick=function(e) {
        hiya(num);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(link);
}
writelink(1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I never see link1 and link3 with this change.

Comment: hi @nonesuch, dont know what you had done - have updated with the whole script I used as test. Hope it helps.